# Qt License in next versions

Tags: qt

Can LGPL license in the newest version of Qt be changed?

Ofcourse new versions can have diffrent license, and can be released without LGPL license.
But how about already released Qt? Can the license be changed?

Comment: If it’s out there under license X, it’s out there under license X. Also see the KDE Free Qt foundation: http://www.kde.org/community/whatiskde/kdefreeqtfoundation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not talking about Qt, but generally. Of course the license can be changed at any time, but this doesn't affect the code that you already have, unless the license you had it under was explicitly time-limited to allow such changes.

Suppose I'm the author of Bobulator project. I've released version 1.0 under a BSD license. You've downloaded it and are using it in your own project.

Sometime later I decide not to offer the project under an open source license. I simply take the source down from my website and that's the last anyone hears about it. Except for those who have already downloaded it and have it, and can certainly use it subject to the terms of the license the code was originally released under. Those include, for example, the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org) :)

Case in point: [VivaCore Library now](http://www.viva64.com/en/vivacore-library/) and [then](https://web.archive.org/web/20110826214438/http://www.viva64.com/en/vivacore-library/). It's based on prof. Chiba's [opencxx](http://opencxx.sourceforge.net). Oops. The internet remembers :) Of course the library's provenance [wasn't meant to be a secret](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0013/).

I'm not a lawyer.